# Passing Multiple objects To Each other

Tags: java, oop, pass-by-value

This is a little weird question, I have a **GUI** class that in the constructor initiates a **Logic** class that takes care of the processing of the Processing or Logistics in the App then their is a **Handler** class that contains a bunch of `ActionListners` `KeyListeners` that are attached to UI components in the **GUI** class

In Constructor of both the **Logic** and **Handler** class I take in as parameter the **GUI** class to be able to manipulate the **GUI** components created in the **GUI** class from both the **Logic** and **Handler** classes

My problem is that The **Handler**  makes use of the **Logic** class and vise versa (the **Logic** class uses the **Handler** class) and thats not really possible with the method I described above, one is instance before the other, one will be null when attempting to use the other.

Example:

```
public class GUI() 
{
    this.handler = new Handler(this);
    this.logic = new Logic(this);
}
```

If `handler` tries to use something in `logic` then `null` would be returned.

One way to fix this is to a setter for the `handler` to take the `logic` and vise versa but that doesn't seem like the answer to this.

Comment: Just use setter methods instead of constructors to pass these references to each other. i.e., `logic.setHandler(handler)` and `handler.setLogic(logic)`. It's really not a big issue.

Comment: I'd create the Logic in the main, pass the Logic to the GUI constructor, and have the GUI instantiate the Handler. I don't think that the Logic should talk to the Handler directly.

Comment: These classes know too much about each other. Cyclic references across objects of different classes/uses are a code smell. I would refactor so that you can break the dependency cycle.

Comment: maybe you're right, i'll see if I can rectify that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple:

```
public class GUI() 
{
    this.handler = new Handler(this);
    this.logic = new Logic(this);
    handler.setLogic(logic);
    logic.setHandler(handler);
}
```

Comment: ya, I guess thats the only way, I was thinking there was a more elegant way of doing that but it works, thanks!

Comment: @Epicmaster: What's inelegant about it?

Comment: no, its just I was imagining there was some way that didn't involve the setter, since setters are Optional and Constructors are Obligatory I don't want a case where the setter is forgotten to be used. But I guess this is the only way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible just to expose the Handler and Logic in GUI, and let the public access it.  By doing so, as your Handler and Logic already have reference to GUI, they can indirectly get access to each other:

```
class Gui {
  private Handler handler;
  private Logic logic;

  public Handler getHandler() {
    return this.handler;
  }
  public Logic getLogic() {
    return this.logic;
  }
}

class Handler {
  private Gui gui;
  public Handler(Gui gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    // access logic
    this.gui.getLogic().doSomeLogic();
  }
}
```

Regarding to "elegance", I don't think the original design of (imho) messy dependencies between component is elegant at all :)  So, instead of focusing making such things look "elegant", do some rethinking and possibly you will find everything become much more elegant automatically. :)

Comment: I like this better than my answer. 1+

Answer (score 0):

Right before your first usage of `handler` and `logic` you could put this code snippet
if(handler == null)
 this.handler = new Handler(this);
if(logic == null)
 this.logic = new Logic(this);

Comment: How does this address the original question, the one about passing references of hander to logic and logic to handler?

Comment: It prevents GUI from being null.

Comment: But that's not his problem. He has no issue of the GUI being null since all of the above is being called from within the GUI class. He wants to set the handler to the logic and visa versa, making sure that neither of them are null. Your code above adds nothing to this solution.

Comment: I agree with @Hovercraft Full Of Eels this doesn't really solve the issue. I want to pass the Logic and Handler object to each other with out one being null in the others instanced object. The GUI isn't the issue.